# Chrome extensions settings - are they portable?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, google-chrome-extensions

As of 2023 Chrome extensions' settings seem to be located on Windows in:
`%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 1\Local Extension Settings`

They are stored using LevelDB (one `.ldb` file per extension).

I'm wondering, what would the easiest way to backup these settings with least manual work?

If I simply copy `Local Extension Settings` folder to another Profile or to another PC will these settings load out of the box without issues? Of course I assume that the other Profile/PC already has the same extensions in place, so we're essentialy just swapping the `.ldb` files.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if you want to copy the settings over to another PC or if you want to just backup your Chrome extensions' settings for future use. If the latter is the case, they are backed up already by Chrome. You can check what is backed up here `chrome://settings/syncSetup/advanced`.

Comment: Chrome's settings and extensions can be synced, but not Chrome extensions' settings.